# AWS SimpleDB BatchPutAttributes returning 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

Some of my batch calls are working (5 out of 8 succeeded). I have no idea why the other 3 batch calls are not working, please can anyone help? I am doing batch calls of 25 every 10 minutes.

Below is the ERROR logs:

`` SimpleDB domain: "Error executing "BatchPutAttributes" on "https://sdb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Server error: `POST https://sdb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `503 Service Unavailable ``

Answer (score 0):

I think your batch put operations or the from other tenants are just exhausting the SimpleDB instance with regular operations. The [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/APIError.html) only says this about 503 error

> 503 Service Unavailable
>
> Service Amazon SimpleDB is busy handling other requests, likely due to
>   too many simultaneous requests. Consider reducing the frequency of
>   your requests, and try again

There is no limit mentioned in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDBLimits.html) about the frequencey of operations. But you can try to check the response for BoxUsage element as mentioned here:

> BoxUsage : The measure of machine utilization for this request. This
>   does not include storage or transfer usage.

This may give you an indication about whether the machine handling your request is too busy.